# Extracting min and max value from points shapefile

Tags: qgis, spatial-statistics

I have a DEM/grid with elevation values that's patchy and I have linear features crossing these areas. What I wanted to do is to measure the min and max elevation points falling along the line.

My approach was to sample the line at a given sample rate and create point features, then get the elevation of this line of points from the DEM/grid, but how can I know look to those points to get min and max points only?

Then how I want to proceed is to copy min and max values as an attribute to the line I have, I think this can be done using ID's?

Comment: Are you asking how the `min()` and `max()` expression work, or how to use the statistics tool?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the field-calculator to extract min and max value into a new field of your line layer with the following type of expression - example for max value, same for min value with `array_min`:

```
array_max(with_variable('my_series', 
      generate_series(0,$length,10),
      array_foreach(@my_series,  
      raster_value('dem',1, 
      line_interpolate_point($geometry,@element)))))
```

this makes a series of points anlong the line - every 10 meters in the example above - and then gets the rastervalues from the layer "dem" and put them into an array...

Comment: I'll have a try with your suggestion, still a rookie with writing expression. However, after several attempts I managed to get the following solution:

1) get a unique ID on each line